# Ctools popup is not working

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

Ctools popup is not working for me. Sharing the effort i made. Any suggestion will be appreciated..

```
function my_test_menu()
{
$items = array();
  $items['my_test/page'] = array(
    'title'=> 'my test page',
    'page callback' => 'my_test_page_callback',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
 $items['mytest/%ctools_js/modal'] = array(
    'title'=> 'modal contents',
    'page callback' => 'my_ajax_test_page_callback',
    'page arguments'=> array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

these are callback functions :--

```
//menu callback
function my_test_page_callback()
{
ctools_include('ajax');
ctools_include('modal');
ctools_modal_add_js();
    $build['paragraph'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<p>',
    '#suffix' => '</p>',
    '#markup' => t('click on the button to show a cool modal'),
   );
$link = ctools_modal_text_button(t('Show a popup'), 'mytest/nojs/modal', t('Show a popup By clicking'),  'ctools-modal-ctools-sample-style');
$build['popup_link'] = array(
'#markup' => $link,
);
return render($build);
}

//ajax call back
function my_ajax_test_page_callback($js = NULL)
{
if($js)
    {
       ctools_include('ajax');
       ctools_include('modal');
    }
       $title = t('my cool popup');
       $build = array(
       '#prefix' => '<strong>',
       '#suffix' => '<strong>',
       '#markup' => t('Hello world! From a cool module'),
       );
return ctools_modal_render($title,$build);    

}
```

Comment: Working!!! made the default jquery version as 1.10.